# How can I get the type of the method invoker in JDT Parser?

Tags: parsing, eclipse-jdt

I tried all these proposals but they didn't work with me especially

```
node.getExpression().resolveTypeBinding()
```

it throws

```
nullPointerException.
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Could you please post some more code of yours?

Comment: Either Node or the returned Expression is null...It'd help if you posted more code.

Comment: it works with me now, but i have another problem which is :  i have a method Invocation and its invoker is another method expression, when i apply the above method ( node.getExpression().resolveTypeBinding()) it doesn't work, i tried also ((MethodInvocation)node.getExpression()).resolveMethodBinding())